# SquishIt load already compressed file

Tags: c#, squishit

Hello i'm using [Squishit](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt) to minify my .js and .css files. Recently i have added new layout and application start took to much time because of Squishit minification.

Is there any way to 'tell' squishit to load recently minified files if the persist on had drive?

I don't want squishit to render new minified files each time application start or incorporated js or css changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to newest version of Squishit solved this problem. Now clod run takes half minute instead of 10 mins.